# The difference between relative adverb and relative pronoun

Tags: grammar, adverbs

What's the difference between a relative adverb and relative pronoun ?

Like in a sentence *This is the place where he was assaulted.* how where is modifying the verb **was assaulted**. I have been reading Wren and Martin for grammar it just says that the adverb modifies the verb but not how. I have also watched videos regarding the relative adverbs and in one video by KHAN ACADEMY, David who is the tutor just says "technically the adverb *where* is modifying the verb" but does not explains.

I want like a complete description like in this way it is modifying a verb or something like that.

Comment: The relative word “where” functions as an adjunct (adverbial) of place in the relative clause “where he was assaulted”, which is modifying the noun “place”. Adjuncts of place typically tell us where something occurred, so it is clear that "where" is modifying the verb "assaulted". Compare “he was assaulted in/at this place”, where the PP “in/at this place” tells us where he was assaulted, and hence is an adjunct of place.

Comment: @BillJ So it's like where is telling where assault took place by relating the clause (containing the verb) to another clause ?

Comment: How's where telling anything about "was assaulted" ?

Comment: In sentence like the sun shines brightly it's crystal clear that brightly is modifying the meaning of shines. But in the above example instead of relying simply on grammarians that they just say that where modifies verb and that's it, i want an explanation

Comment: @BillJ Where you are going to answer in comments, please write an answer.